# iPhone 4 apps disappeared after update

Tags: iphone

I recently had an update done on my iPhone 4 at a local Verizon store because I don't have internet at home. My phone wasn't wanting to update but eventually did but they ordered me a replacement phone long story.

All my apps and pictures came up on my phone and some loaded but I didn't have time to wait on all them to load. They said when you get around Wi-Fi just resume the download. With my job I haven't been around Wi-Fi. Yesterday I noticed some of my apps are missing off my phone. What may have happened?

Answer (score 1):

there could be a couple things off the top of my head.

- resume download has been iffy for me.  but go into the app store and go to the purchased history and all your previous apps will be in there.  you'll just have to download them and rearrange to how you like them.
- but consider those may no longer compatible with the new ios version?  doesn't sound like it from how you described it but...

Comment: +1 for the first point, but with regard to the second point afaik developers can set a minimum iOS version but not a maximum iOS version?

Answer (score 1):

You mention that you've had a replacement phone and therefore presume you're restoring an iCloud backup. If this backup is interrupted, next time the device connects to Wi-Fi the device will prompt you to continue the restoring. If you cancel this, the restore is cancelled. To continue the restore, you will have to start the restore process again by erasing your content and restoring from the iCloud backup.